# Galvanic-coupled switch ground tracing

Tags: switches, noise, switching, level-shifting

How trace power switch ground in right way?
All signals must have as short traces as it can. But i forced to pass **weak signal** through the entire **noisy power ground** if im have galvanic coupling (drawing 2), otherwise, **noisy power signal** will pass through **clear signal ground** (drawing 1).

Also, i can make a level shifter circuit and drive the switch with **shifted empowered signal**. (drawing 3).
But if i havent this option (no space, parts, not so bad case and etc), i should use circuit at drawing 2.
Is im right, or is there some another ways?

[image: Drawing 1 and 2][Drawing 1 and 2]
[image: Drawing 3][Drawing 3]

Comment: Translate your tracks into resistors. There are online calcs that will estimate track resistance for you. Once you know the resistance and the current, you can solve for voltage. Determine if the voltage drop causes a problem. Also, be aware the tracks have inductance, so it can be easy to make an oscillator - especially if you use mosfets. The general solution is to size your tracks so you don!5 have a problem and use a star grounding technique or groundplane. Arrange your layout such that high currents dont flow across sensitive areas.

Comment: The star grounging causes this "problem". Also it is not a problem, i just cant found "right" solution, between this three variants.

Comment: If you have a ground bounce problem, then something like drawing3 is a possible solution but your actual is incorrect. With any engineering solution, you need to qualify and quantify otherwise we’re just talking fluff. The groundbounce could be insignificant or megavolts or somewhere in between. Put some numbers to it.

Comment: Im just try to figure out - the rule of thumb for this. Before i meet any noises and before any measurements, when i'm creating first PCB iteration and know, that there is some possible noisy load. In figure 3 (and on all others too) i mean not NPN, but just some-amplifier.